Cutting the Klein bottle with a one-sided curve
I would like to know what we can get if we cut the Klein bottle along a one-sided simple closed curve. Here a simple closed curve is one-sided if it has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to the (open) Möbius band.
I have tried several times, and it seems that no matter which one-sided curve I choose, it always results in a Möbius band. Is this a fact? How can we understand it?
I would also appreciate any textbook references.

Not sure what a "non-orientable closed curve" ($1$-dimensional) is, but recall that a Klein bottle, in fact any connected compact surface, can be be seen as a disc with identifications along the edge.

@AndreaMori I fixed it as one-sided curve.

and what is the side of a curve??

@AndreaMori curve is one-sided if, loosely speaking, the right side becomes the left side after walking along the curve.

@Salomo A curve has no sides. Please give us a definition.

@BenSteffan A definition is just added.

@Salomo: a one-dimensional curve has no sides. What you are thinking of are orientable and non-orientable surfaces. A Klein bottle is non-orientable.

If you know the classification of surfaces, this is a simple exercise.

If you know the classification of closed surfaces, here's a simple outline (if you don't know that classification, all I can say is: learn it!). Everything I say will be "up to homeomorphism", for example the next sentence.
A Klein bottle $K$ is a closed, nonorientable surface of Euler characteristic zero.
When you cut $K$ open along a one-sided curve $C$, the resulting surface $K \setminus C$ has Euler characteristic zero and one boundary component.
If you then fill in that boundary component by attaching a disc $D$, you get a closed surface $P = (K \setminus C) \cup D$ of Euler characteristic $1$.
It follows that $P$ is a projective plane, which is the only closed surface of Euler characteristic $1$.
Removing the interior of any disc from a projective plane (such as the disc $D$) always results in a Möbius band.
